# $set vs $addField in mongoDb Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

With **MongoDb 4.2**, we have new aggregation stage `$set`. As per docs,

> `$set` stage is an alias for `$addFields` (from mongoDb 3.4)

But nothing mentioned why the need to have two stages with same functionality.

Can someone help to understand this ? (possibly since versions < 4.0 will be depricated soon )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB 4.2 introduced update commands that can accept an aggregation pipeline.

`$set` has long been an update operator, which does the same thing in updates as the `$addFields` stage does in aggregation.

Permitting either name to be used in an aggregation pipeline eases the adoption of the new update command.

Comment: Warning, update $set and aggregate $set are totally different -- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-42084?focusedCommentId=4477916&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-4477916